# Translate a vector from global space to local vector in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

With a rotated object in my scene, how can I translate a global vector into the local space of that rotated object, so that they are rendered in the same spot of the global vector?

Take for example a cube that is rotated but at the global origin. Now I would like to render lines for each global dimension (x, y, z), but added as children to the rotated cube, not the global scene. **How do I calculate and in three.js implement the rotation of those vectors so they will line up?**

Comment: Is `object.worldToLocal( vector )` what you are looking for?

Comment: @WestLangley That was my first instinct as well, but that doesn't seem to get me what I want... so either I might be using it wrong, or that is not the solution. Assuming this does what I want, drawing a line along the following vector it should line up to the global X axis (which for me, it doesn't), should it not? `var translatedAxis = myRotatedObject.worldToLocal(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));`

Comment: Can you provide a simple live example, such as a jsfiddle?

Comment: See here: http://jsbin.com/datiyekaroti/1/

Comment: Hey @WestLangley thanks for checking again. I ended up translating the Vector3 itself with applyMatrix4, but the `parent.updateMatrixWorld(); // important!` was the crucial missing piece. Feel free to add a reference to that as an answer and I'll gladly accept. :)

Comment: Oops. My fiddle was in error. I deleted my previous comment. See the answer posted below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to add an object as a child of a parent object such that the *world position and orientation of the child do not change*.

You can do that using the following pattern:

```
parent.attach( object );
```

three.js r.107